# Playing Two Sounds in iOS Using Swift 2.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, avaudioplayer

I have an app that includes a picker wheel and a play button.  When the user selects the desired sound and clicks the play button, the sound will play.  In addition to this, I have a "Random" button that will generate a random number, move the picker wheel to the appropriate array index and then plays the sound.  All of this works OK.

The Issue is that I'm trying to add a "Combo" button that will essentially do the same as the "Random" button but instead of only playing 1 sound I want it to play 2 or 3.

Here is my existing code (problem with the playComboSound function):

```
// Play Audio
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playAudio() {
    do {
        if let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(Sounds[selection], ofType: "mp3") {
            let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: bundle)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

@IBAction func playRandomSound(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Generate Random Number Based on SoundNames Array Count and assign to Selection
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(SoundNames.count)))
    selection = randomNumber

    // Move Picker Wheel to Match Random Number and Play Sound
    self.picker.selectRow(selection, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    playAudio()
}

@IBAction func playComboSound(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Generate Random Number Based on SoundNames Array Count and assign to Selection
    let randomNumber1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(SoundNames.count)))
    selection = randomNumber1

    // Move Picker Wheel to Match Random Number and Play Sound
    self.picker.selectRow(selection, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    playAudio()

    // Generate Random Number Based on SoundNames Array Count and assign to Selection
    let randomNumber2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(SoundNames.count)))
    selection = randomNumber2

    // Move Picker Wheel to Match Random Number and Play Sound
    self.picker.selectRow(selection, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    playAudio()
}
```

When I click the playComboSound button it basically does the same as the playRandomSound button.  Moves the picker wheel and plays the sound, but it only does it once instead of twice.  If I put a sleep in between I get some level of success in playing two sounds, but it only ever seems to move the picker wheel once (for the second sound).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: @TamasZahola great answer! basically you need to create a second audioPlayer... `audioPlayer2` so that you can play two sounds at once. Otherwise, when you go to play the second sound, the first one is stopped and replaced by the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Moves the picker wheel and plays the sound, but it only does it once instead of twice.

It plays the sound once, because the second call to `playAudio` overwrites the shared `audioPlayer` variable with a new `AVAudioPlayer` instance which deallocates the first one. You should keep an array/set of references to all the active audio players to to prevent them from being deallocated, and only remove them from this set once they've finished (use `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` callbacks to detect when a player has finished).

> If I put a sleep in between I get some level of success in playing two sounds, but it only ever seems to move the picker wheel once (for the second sound).

The sleep helps because while the main thread is sleeping, AVFoundation's threads have a chance to run and they can start playback for the first `AVAudioPlayer`, before the second call to `playAudio` overwrites it and  it's deallocated. You're relying on an undefined behaviour here though.

> it only ever seems to move the picker wheel once (for the second sound)

This is the expected behaviour. Only a single item can be selected on a picker wheel. The second call to `selectRow` overrides the first one.

Comment: Thanks Tamas for the quick response.  I'm not sure what you mean by:

"You should keep an array/set of references to all the active audio players to to prevent them from being deallocated, and only remove them from this set once they've finished (use AVAudioPlayerDelegate callbacks to detect when a player has finished)."

Should I create two separate audio players? (audioPlayer1, audioPlayer2)?

Comment: You should have a set or array of AVAudioPlayers instead of a single field: `var audioPlayers:[AVAudioPlayer] = []`. And then in `playAudio()` you should create an `AVAudioPlayer` and add it to `audioPlayers`: `self.audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)`. When the playback has finished you shold remove them from `audioPlayers` so that you don't leak memory. This can be achieved via `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` finish/error callbacks: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008068